# How to make changes to a created object in Java

Tags: java, arrays

The following code works all the way up until where the user enters the score for the team `int homeScore = input.nextInt()`, at which point the compiler returns the following error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
    at assignment.PremierLeagueManager.main(PremierLeagueManager.java:121)
Java Result: 1
```

Any idea's on how to fix this?

```
boolean validHome = false;
boolean validAway = false;
System.out.println("Enter name of Home team: ");
String homeName = input.next();

Iterator<FootballClub> it = premierLeague.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    if (it.next().getClubName().equals(homeName)) {
        validHome = true;
    }
}

System.out.println("Enter name of Away team: ");
String awayName = input.next();
Iterator<FootballClub> it2 = premierLeague.iterator();

while (it2.hasNext()) {
    if (it2.next().getClubName().equals(awayName)) {
        validAway = true;
    }
}

if (validHome == true && validAway == true) {
    System.out.println("Enter number of goals scored by " + homeName + ":");
    int homeScore = input.nextInt();
    int x = premierLeague.indexOf(it.next());
    premierLeague.get(x).setGoalsScored(homeScore);

    System.out.println("Enter number of goals scored by " + awayName + ":");
    int awayScore = input.nextInt();
    int y = premierLeague.indexOf(it2.next());
    premierLeague.get(y).setGoalsScored(awayScore);
} else {
    System.out.println("One of the teams are invalid. Please try again");
}
```

Comment: What do you have at line 121 in PremierLeagueManager.java?

Comment: Please fix the indendation.

Comment: Please provide the SSCCE. http://sscce.org/

Comment: The title of your question isn't the question you are asking.  Please fix that.

Answer (score 1):

At the top where you do "while (it.hasNext())", this loops until the iterator has no more items, so when you get to "int x = premierLeague.indexOf(it.next());", there is no next item for the iterator, so you get no such element.  If you want to start over, you need to create a new iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `it.next()` after the call to `input.nextInt()`, but there is no guarantee that there is any member in the iterator `it`. I'm not sure this is the problem, but it looks like it.

You don't tell us what the line numbers of your source is, and it is confusing that you say this is a compiler error when it looks like it is a runtime error. But that looks like an error, in any event (and you do that twice).